# Why does sprintf not work when \"%s\" is used?

Tags: c

I'm using sprintf with the IMXRT1021 NXP microcontroller but not getting the required output.

Library: Redlib (nohost-nf)

I have tried both ways but the result is the same.

```
sprintf(at,"AT=\x22%s\x22,\x22%s\x22\r\n","abcdef","123456");

sprintf(at,"AT=\"%s\",\"%s\"\r\n","abcdef","123456");
```

Expected output:

```
AT="abcdef","123456"\r\n
```

Actual output:

```
AT=\"abcdef\",\"123456\"\r\n
```

Comment: Seeing the backslashes back is quite unusual, any C compiler removes them.  Do make sure it is not the debugger doing this.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? The code seems fine.

Comment: Your debugger is showing the backslashes.

Comment: Where are you seeing this output? I'd be tempted to get absolute clarity by looking in the debugger at the actual memory content starting at `at`.

Comment: Can you clarify where you see this output? On the terminal/UART or some place else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you are talking about.

If you were to output this into a terminal, the string you would see is the one you expected:

```
AT="abcdef","123456"   # plus newline etc.
```

However, the C *representation* of that string is:

```
"AT=\"abcdef\",\"123456\"\r\n"
```

Comment: Earlier I was checking in debugger and got wrong result and also there was some other issue which cause error so I thought string has an issue but later on I confirmed by checking each element of array.